# Where do i call websocket plugin to keep it always openned?

Tags: javascript, plugins, websocket, nuxt.js

I am working with websockets on nuxt.js proyect, and i need to keep the connection **opened** and **unique** (singleton), but i could not achieve it.

I created a custom plugin where i listen for ws events, and openned the connection (checking if it doesnt exists yet -but sometimes it creates several ws instances-), and im calling this plugin from a middleware, which is using in several layouts.

The problem is:

1. Sometimes the connection does not establish (on page reload i.e.). How can i make sure it always starts on user login and keep openned till logout?
2. How do i keep just one instance of my plugin?

This is the plugin file i wrote:

```
export default ({ store, $axios, app }, inject) => {

class EasyWebsocket {
roomNotifications = ''

isOpen() {
  return this.roomNotifications && this.roomNotifications.readyState === 1
}

initRoomNotifications(token) {
  // if already open do nothing
  if (this.isOpen()) {
    return
  }
  console.log('inicializando notifications websocket')
  this.roomNotifications = new WebSocket(
    `wss://api/ws/chat/?t=${token}`
  )
  const self = this

  this.roomNotifications.onmessage = async function(event) {
    // CAPTURING THE WEBSOCKET NOTIFICATION
    const { data } = event
    const { event_type, room } = JSON.parse(data)

    // TODO FRANCO: VER EL CONTADOR DE UNREADMESSAGES
    const count = store.state.dashboard.chat.unreadMessagesCount + 1
    store.commit('dashboard/chat/SET_UNREAD_MESSAGES_COUNT', count)

    switch (event_type) {
      case 'ROOM_UPDATED':
        console.log('new message', room) // no borrar
        await self.newRoomNotification(room)
        break
      case 'NEW_INVITATION':
        console.log('created room', room) // no borrar
        await self.newInvitation(room)
        break
      case 'NEW_MESSAGES':
        console.log('new messages room', room) // no borrar

        await self.newRoomNotification(room)
        if (
          store.getters['dashboard/chat/isActive']({ conversation: room })
        )
          store.commit('dashboard/chat/ADD_MESSAGE', room.last_message)
        break
      default:

        break
    }
  }
  this.roomNotifications.onopen = function(event) {
    console.log('opening NOTIFICATION WEBSOCKET --------------', event) //  no borrar
  }
  this.roomNotifications.onclose = function(event) {

  }
  this.roomNotifications.onerror = function(event) {
  }
}

newInvitation(room) {
  const invitations = store.getters['dashboard/chat/invitations']
  const newInvitations = [room, ...invitations]
  store.commit('dashboard/chat/SET_INVITATIONS', newInvitations)
}

async newRoomNotification(room) {
  const { name } = room
  // GET ALL CONVERSATIONS
  const conversations = store.getters['dashboard/chat/visibleConversations']
  // FIND CONVERSATION INDEX
  const conversationIndex = conversations.findIndex(
    (conv) => conv.name === name
  )
  const newConversations = [...conversations]

   if (conversationIndex === -1) {
     const conversation = await $axios.$get(
       `v2/chat/rooms/${name}/?archived=false`
     )
     newConversations.unshift(conversation)
   }  else {
     newConversations[conversationIndex] = {
       ...newConversations[conversationIndex],
       ...room
     }
   }
   store.commit('dashboard/chat/SET_CONVERSATIONS', newConversations)
  }
 }
 inject('easyWebsocket', EasyWebsocket)
}
```

Then in the middleware file:

```
  export default async function({ store, $auth, $easyWebsocket }) {
if (!$auth.$state.loggedIn) return

// calling just on client side (websocket doesnt work on ss)
if (process.client) {
  $easyWebsocket.prototype.initRoomNotifications(
    //userdata
  )
}

try {
  await store.dispatch('dashboard/chat/getUnreadMessagesCount')
} catch (error) {}
```

}

Comment: What is this middleware file? Where is it located?

Comment: In the nuxt middleware directory. I found a workaround: handle the ws state from vuex. But now my plugin is less cohesive

Comment: Do you call it globally in your `nuxt.config.js` file?

Comment: Yes, as a client plugin (no ssr)